# Database same row concurrent read and update

Tags: mysql, database, django

I have an application with a row that EVERY user reads and updates constantly (almost every request) this causes DB locks and loss of data.

The problem is that it's critical information and everyone must have it synchronized and updated.

I can introduce a small delay in the update info but it must be synchronized for all users.

I'm using Django and MySql.

**Note**: To keep the application working I'm issuing the update in a separate thread. So even if the update fails it's not waiting for the lock to end to continue.

Comment: Which engine do you use?

Comment: check the following link: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/select-update-single-statement-race-condition

Comment: If you use innodb engine, consider using transactions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: What about [F() object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)?